# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{3}+x+1}}dx$

Tags: integration, limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{3}+x+1}}dx$$
I tried to use $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}=\ln(x+{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}})$ but I don't get that squares from $x^{3}+x+1$.Also I took $u=x^{3}+x+1$ and $du=3x^{2}+1$  but I didn't get too far.Same for $u=\sqrt{x^{3}+x+1}$.

Some hints?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one: since the integrand is a positive decreasing function of $x$, one has
$$0\le \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{3}+x+1}}\,\mathrm dx\le\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3}+n+1}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3}+n+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3}}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Why in the second integral you replaced x with n ?And how you know that the second integral is equal with the function itself ?

Comment: Actually, I use the *mean value inequality*. The second involves the function evaluated at $n$ because the latter is a constant w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: If m=minimum of f(x) and M=maximum of f(x) then $m(b-a)\leq \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\leq M(b-a)$ Do you applied this inequality?

Comment: Absolutely (the right side inequality).

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x+1}}\,dx$ converges, so for every $\varepsilon$ there exists $M>0$ such that $$\int_M^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x+1}}\,dx<\varepsilon$$
It follows that for $n>M$,
$$\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x+1}}\,dx < \int_M^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x+1}}\,dx<\varepsilon$$
and since the integral is positive, this proves that the limit of the l.h.s is zero.

Comment: The key here is that the integrand tends to $0$ as $x\to \infty $. The convergence of integral is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) > 0$
and
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$
then
$0
\lt \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
\le \max(f(x))|_{x=n}^{n+1}
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$.

If, in addition,
$f'(x) < 0$,
then
$0
\lt \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
\le f(n)
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$.

In your case,
$f(x)
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^{3}+x+1}}
$satisfies these,
so
$ \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
\le f(n)
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3}+n+1}}
\lt \dfrac1{n^{3/2}}
$.